# MongoDB: How to remove data at index 1 in v field (Nested Document)

Tags: c#, mongodb

In given nested document unable to remove data at "v" field index 1 using $pull. Currently I am able to find the record but not able to update it.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac46fe0d2306b0fd746a09c"),
"a" : LUUID("26911ace-d615-9940-bcb7-fb07d2430995"),
"b" : null,
"c" : ISODate("2018-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
"v" : {
    "0" : {
        "d" : {
            "Quality" : {
                "s" : "ABC",
                "v" : "123"
            },
            "GOT" : {
                "s" : "CBZ",
                "v" : "555"
            }
        },
        "e" : 741.3
    },
    "1" : {
        "d" : {
            "Quality" : {
                "s" : "CDF",
                "v" : "456"
            }
        },
        "e" : 711.3
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just reading the docs on `$pull`. It says it's for using it to remove elements from an array but you don't have an array?

Comment: its working with $unset only.

Comment: So what's the problem? Why do you need to use `$pull`? That's for arrays but from what you have shown you're trying to remove from an object so it will never work.

Comment: Actually they have used indexes, So I thought $push will work here. I didn't try $unset before. Actually I am handling this data through Dictionary on .net side. So I thought $pull will work with dictionary. But I was wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify your question with a desired outcome, and what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: In above document I wanted to remove 1st index in "v" field. As they have saved data in the form of index in  this "v" field, so I thought this is an array, so I was using `$pull` but it was not working. Finally I found this `$unset` and I was able to remove record at 1st index. But I am confused in how to remove whole document, if "v" field is empty. Any suggestion?